# foreach value from input form

Tags: php, foreach

please help me. i have a problem with my code.

This is code input.php :

```
<form method="POST" action="simpan.php">
NIM : <input type="text" required placeholder="input NIM" name="nim"/><br/>
Name : <input type="text" required placeholder="input name" name="nama"/><br/>
score : <input type="number" required placeholder="input score between 0-100" name="score"/><br/><input type="submit" value="OK"/>
```

This is code simpan.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['nim'][] = $_POST['nim'];
    $_SESSION['nama'][] = $_POST['nama'];
    $_SESSION['nilai'][] = $_POST['score'];

    header("location:index.php")
?>
```

and This is code show.php :

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    foreach($_SESSION as $key)
    {
            foreach($key as $data => $value)
            {
            echo "NIM : ",$value." ", "Name : ",$value." ", "Score : ",$value." ";              
            }
    }
?>
```

the result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c83SH.png)
And the problem is I want to show the input with format
Nim:
Name:
score:

example = nim:01 name: john score:90

What should I change in show.php in order to appear according to the above format?
thanks :)

Comment: `echo $value," ";` should be `echo $value." ";`

Comment: you are not getting error at  echo $value," ";  line. try to change  as mentioned in above comment.

Comment: Commas work for concatenating too don't they? Can you show us what your output looks like?

Comment: You can check the example here i did https://3v4l.org/bZnTv

Comment: @webpic : The output that I want is like that = nim:xxx name:xxx score:xxx

Comment: @ArifMaulana what is the reason you had take array in session?? $_SESSION['nim'][] = $_POST['nim']; you can simply take like  $_SESSION['nim'] = $_POST['nim'];

Comment: @BunkerBoy woow thanks so much.. its solved.. Big thanks

Comment: @Arif Maulana your welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arif Maulana just change your show.php to like below hope this is what you want:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $echoString = "";
    foreach($_SESSION as $key => $sessionArr){
            if($key == "nama"){
                $echoString .= "name : ";
            }
            else if($key == "nilai"){
                $echoString .= "score : ";
            }
            else{
                $echoString .= $key." : ";
            }

            foreach($sessionArr as $value)
            {
                $echoString .= $value." ";
            }
    }
    echo $echoString;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below example i did https://3v4l.org/CcOOK

```
 <?php

 $_POST['nim'] = 'Hrllo';
 $_POST['nama'] = 'Data';
 $_POST['score'] = '33';

$_SESSION['nim'][] = $_POST['nim'];
$_SESSION['nama'][] = $_POST['nama'];
$_SESSION['score'][] = $_POST['score'];


$string = '';
foreach($_SESSION as $main_key => $key)
    {
            foreach($key as $data => $value)
            {
             $string .= $main_key . ":" . $value . ' ';                
            }

    }
    $string = rtrim($string, ' ');
    echo $string;
```

Comment: What if the output is like this= nim:Hrllo  nama:Data score:33

Comment: @ArifMaulana Updated the answer